# Select, stored procedure and XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns XML. Now what I am doing is this: I have a second query which also generates XML. What I want is this: insert XML from stored procedure in the second sql. Is it possible?

A very simplified pseudo code for SQL is something like this:

```
Select id, name, age,
(
   EXEC Address id -- this already returns xml. How can i insert XML here?
)
from Persons
FOR XML PATH('Person')
```

I do not want to change the stored procedure because it is maintained by another group.

Comment: Regardless of XML, you cannot execute a stored procedure from within a query. You *can* call a function, but it will not perform well.

Comment: Any other suggestion? Other than function? What about inserting data from procedure in a temp table and then perform select query on it to get XML? Will that be faster compared to function call?

Comment: I don't see how you could do it with the procedure in your example. Maybe if you could pass it a TVP with Person Ids and get back a rowset with addresses in an XML column. How many persons and addresses are you going to retrieve at a time?

Comment: What I meant to say is this: Get all the Address before Select statement in a temp table. I will have to use stored procedure to fill the temp table. After that, SELECT query will be executed. And instead of EXEC, I can call SELECT on temp table. I am pretty sure it is possible, but I am not sure about the performance.

Comment: Joining with the temp table to build the complete XML will be fine. Populating the temp table will be slow, because it will be a RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) operation. But if you are only gong to get 10-20 addresses at a time, I wouldn't worry about the performance too much.